# column with previous value "Month"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this example of df

I do some transformations on it and I need to get my mark value from the previous month in a new column to make comparisons

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthEnd



df = pd.DataFrame({'Found':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
   'Date':['14/10/2021','19/10/2021','29/10/2021','30/09/2021','20/09/2021','20/10/2021','29/10/2021','15/09/2021','30/09/2021'],
   'Mark':[1,2,3,4,3,1,2,5,8]

  })

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['LastDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) - BMonthEnd(0)
```

[image]

I'm using group by to get the highest value for each month and create a new column with that value but I can also use a lambda function.

```
mark_last_day = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: x['Date']==x['LastDay'], 1)]

or

__ = .[.(['Found', 'LastDay'])['Mark'].max()]

df.merge(mark_last_day[['Found', 'LastDay', 'Mark']],
     on=['Found', 'LastDay'],
     how='left', suffixes=['', '_LastDay'])
```

resulting in this

[image]

how can I create a new column with the result of the previous month as in this example I filled in manually

[image]

Comment: do you what the business end of month for your last day?  BMonthEnd

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with `freq='BM'`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y/%m/%d')
df['LastDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) - BMonthEnd(0)

s1 = df.set_index('Mark').groupby(['Found', 'LastDay'])['Date'].idxmax()
s2 = s1.reset_index(level=0).groupby(['Found'])['Date'].shift(freq='BM')

df = df.join(pd.concat([s1.rename('Mark_LastDay'), 
                        s2.rename('Mark_LastDayPrevMonth')], axis=1), 
             on=['Found', 'LastDay'])
print (df)
  Found       Date  Mark    LastDay  Mark_LastDay  Mark_LastDayPrevMonth
0     A 2021-10-14     1 2021-10-29             3                    4.0
1     A 2021-10-19     2 2021-10-29             3                    4.0
2     A 2021-10-29     3 2021-10-29             3                    4.0
3     A 2021-09-30     4 2021-09-30             4                    NaN
4     A 2021-09-20     3 2021-09-30             4                    NaN
5     B 2021-10-20     1 2021-10-29             2                    8.0
6     B 2021-10-29     2 2021-10-29             2                    8.0
7     B 2021-09-15     5 2021-09-30             8                    NaN
8     B 2021-09-30     8 2021-09-30             8                    NaN
```